# Twitter API user model object not returning all of the fields documented

Tags: python, twitter

```
>>> potus = api.GetUser(screen_name='potus')
>>> potus['created_at']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> potus
User(ID=822215679726100480, ScreenName=POTUS)
```

I'm trying to get a basic little script to do analysis of some twitter users, but the api doesn't seem to be returning all of the fields.

This is the python api library I am using:
 https://github.com/bear/python-twitter.git

Comment: I recommend using [agithub](https://github.com/jpaugh/agithub), which works with any REST API. It tailors to REST (only), and does not try to interpret the results returned by the API, so it would help you figure out whether the issue is with Twitter's API, or with the client library you're using. Disclosure: I wrote AGithub.

Comment: You probably wanted `potus.created_at`.

Comment: Thank you internet_user, that was at the solution.